# " Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Education

```
import { deleteEducation } from '../../actions/profile';

const Education = ({ education, deleteEducation }) => {
  const educations = education.map(edu => (
    <tr key={edu._id}>
      <td>{edu.school}</td>
      <td className="hide-sm">{edu.degree}</td>
      <td>
```

here is my code of education.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import moment from 'moment';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteEducation } from '../../actions/profile';

const Education = ({ education, deleteEducation }) => {
  const educations = education.map(edu => (
    <tr key={edu._id}>
      <td>{edu.school}</td>
      <td className="hide-sm">{edu.degree}</td>
      <td>
        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{moment.utc(edu.from)}</Moment> -{' '}
        {edu.to === null ? (
          ' Now'
        ) : (
          <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{moment.utc(edu.to)}</Moment>
        )}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          onClick={() => deleteEducation(edu._id)}
          className="btn btn-danger"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className="my-2">Education Credentials</h2>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>School</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Degree</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Years</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{educations}</tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Education.propTypes = {
  education: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  deleteEducation: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { deleteEducation }
)(Education);
```

Comment: Seems, `education` is not what you think it it ... More specifically, its `undefined` where is it created? Is it correctly initialized ...

Comment: Use education?.map(…) ,it will check if education array is undefined.

Comment: You should pass the array with some data or empty array i.e. `[]`. You can also give it a default value while destructuring: `const Education = ({ education = [], deleteEducation }) => {`

Comment: @Ajeet Shah your solution `const Education = ({ education = [], deleteEducation }) => { ` removes my error but on the front-end instead of showing original data, it is delivering null value, only a blank page.

Comment: how do i show original data it is showing null value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const educations = education && education.map(edu => .....
```

By using this if education field not exist and empty screen display instead of error.